# json-framework error in iPhone static library

Tags: iphone, static-libraries, json-framework

I have an iPhone app that uses the [json-framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/). I moved some of the code, including the json-framework source, from the main project to a static library. When I did this, the json-framework stopped getting compiled into the binary (double checked with class dump). This causes a nasty error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFString JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x43897f0'
```

Everything else in the static library continues to function properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, categories and static libraries don't work unless you sprinkle the magic dust on the linker flag. According to a [Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2006/qa1490.html), you have to add the -ObjC linker flag to the main project (not the library, as stated in the Q&A).